# Execute Python script with time delay using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, python

I wanted to execute a Python script through a JavaScript file because I would like to print results from a python script into an html page. I started by looking into the `python-shell` module. I followed this tutorial:

http://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/286/how-to-execute-a-python-script-and-retrieve-output-data-and-errors-in-node-js

I was successfully able to follow the tutorial and everything worked correctly.

However, I would now like to print out some numbers in the console with a time delay. My Python script contains the following code:

```
while True:
    print(random.randint(1,101))
    time.sleep(10)
```

When I run my JavaScript code, nothing happens. I did some debugging and removed the `time.sleep()` statement and it works.

What is the correct way to do this? Why does this work when I remove `time.sleep()`?

Comment: Did you use `import time` in your python code?

Comment: Yes I did. The python code works correctly on its own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to flush the standard output stream in your python script after printing.

```
import sys

while True:
    print(random.randint(1,101))
    sys.stdout.flush()
    time.sleep(10)
```

Comment: np, glad that helped!